# REST Hateos: How to make sure that client enters REST application through a simple fixed URL?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, api-design, restful-url, hateoas

We want to create a screen on multiple clients that shows "5 best selling product", "5 recently added product" and "5 product with great offers". All these would be shown as carousel.

We want to create Restful APIs for these. We have created following APIs:

1. /api/bestsellingproduct/
2. /api/recentlyaddedproduct/
3. /api/greatofferproduct/

Currently, every client i.e. desktop, mobile, android, ios has hard-coded these URIs. I am worried if we tomorrow change these URLs, it would be cumbersome and also REST suggests that "A REST client enters a REST application through a simple fixed URL. (Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)"

Can someone suggest how I can ensure that all clients enter application through simple fixed URL in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HATEOAS URIs are discoverable (and not documented) so that they can be changed. That is, unless they are the very entry points into your system ([Cool URIs](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html), the only ones that can be hard-coded by clients) - and you shouldn't have too many of those if you want the ability to evolve the rest of your system's URI structure in the future. This is in fact one of the most [useful](https://morethancoding.com/2011/09/07/uri-construction-give-it-a-rest/) features of REST.

For the remaining non-Cool URIs, they can be changed over time, and your API documentation should spell out the fact that they should be discovered at runtime through hypermedia traversal.

Looking at the [Richardson's Maturity Model (level 3)](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3), this would be where links come into play. For example, from the top level, say /api/version(/1), you would discover there's a link to the groups. Here's how this could look in a tool like [HAL Browser](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal-browser):

Root:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/api/root"
    },
    "api:bestsellingproduct": {
      "href": "http://apiname:port/api/bestsellingproduct"
    },
    "api:recentlyaddedproduct": {
      "href": "http://apiname:port/api/recentlyaddedproduct"
    },
    "api:greatofferproduct": {
      "href": "http://apiname:port/api/greatofferproduct")
    }
  }
}
```

The advantage here would be that the client would only need to know the relationship (link) name (well obviously besides the resource structure/properties), while the server would be mostly free to alter the relationship (and resource) url.

You could even embed them to be returned in the same root api call:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "bestsellingproduct": [
        {               
            "id": "1",
            "name": "prod test"
        },
        {               
            "id": "2",
            "name": "prod test 2"
        }
    ],
    "recentlyaddedproduct": [
        {               
            "id": "3",
            "name": "prod test 3"
        },
        {               
            "id": "5",
            "name": "prod test 5"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. Avoiding such hard-coding would save us only in case of change in URIs in future. We still have to make sure that response body of these changed URIs remain same as that of response of previous URIs. Do we have any way of avoiding such hard-coding of response at client level (as we have done here to avoid hard-code the URIs)?

Comment: models are part of the contract, and are not to be broken; however, if you find yourself in a situation where you would have to break backwards compatibility (e.g. removing a property from the model, because just adding a new one is fine), then you can turn to versioning: you'd have `/api/v1` for the old one, and then `api/v2` and so forth, leaving it to the client to choose the API version

Comment: Our clients have two type of views, one view type has carousel for bestselling/recentlyadded/greatoffer-product. The other view type has image-buttons for product in budget i.e. one image for "mobile-less-than-$100", other for "mobile-less-than-$200". For image button view json would be like [{"title":"mobile-less-than-$100", "URI":"/api/stocks/?budget=0-100"}]. If we want to experiment by moving carousel and button up or down, how should that be handled?